# UIWebView memory leaks when opening images

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, uiwebview, automatic-ref-counting

I'm fighting memory leaks on iOS `UIWebView` for last few days. When I open quite large image (about 10 MB jpeg file) in `UIWebView` memory footprint increases by the size of that image and never goes down. Even if I open same image second time memory is allocated again, and stays until process is ended.

I've tried deallocating `UIWebView` using all possible solutions from [here](http://www.codercowboy.com/code-uiwebview-memory-leak-prevention/) and other stackoverflow posts, but none of them worked. I am also clearing `NSUrlCache` after each request and set cache limits to 0, but still without any effect.

Using memory profiler I was able to get stacktrace of method responsible for leak.
[image: Stack trace]

Do you have any idea how can I deallocate that memory? It is possible that there is some curricular reference in WebCore code and I can't do anything about it?
Do you have any ideas how to fix that leak or do I have to switch to WKWebView or other control?